# Remove trailing comma in vscode snippet transform

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

### What I want

I am trying to transform this:

```
foo awehorihawolvbahvierwba3485y089726y216
bar :aw]\e[;r\a32[5a94t8g-09po
```

into this:

```
foo,
bar
```

### The problem

My current solution is to remove the "junk" and replace it with a comma:

```
$1

${1/(\\w+).*/$1,/gm}
```

This however leaves a trailing comma and I find it annoying to remove the trailing comma every time.

```
foo,
bar,
```

### What I've tried

Take the original idea and nest it into this transform

```
${<insert transform here>/,$//}

... like this ...

${${1/(\\w+).*/$1,/gm}/,$//}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be triggering your snippet and then pasting your text into it, since you are only using `$1` as your input.  If that is not the case, let us know, it would probably be easy to modify this for a selection, etc.

This will work:

```
    "add a comma only if": {
        "prefix": ["py"],           // whatever prefix you want
        "body": [
            "${1/(\\w+).*(?=$(\r?\n)?)/$1${2:+,}/gm}"
            // "${1/(\\w+).*$(\r?\n)?/$1${2:+,\n}/gm}"  // this also works
        ]
    },
```

It will work for any number of input lines, putting a comma at the end of each except the last.

`(?=$(\r?\n)?)` positive lookahead for a newline, if so capture in group 2
`${2:+,}` if a group 2, add a comma

[image: trailing comma demo]

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect :) I wish I could give 1000 upvotes to this for saving me a lot of time haha

Comment: Some day you will be able to ;>}  I added a slight simplification above.   You don't really need a positive lookahead if you put a newline into the conditional transform.  About the same complexity really.